# Use node.js stream to create a file and pipe to gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, fs

I am using node.js. I have a Buffer and I need to write it to a file named 'bla.js' and then pipe gulp's uglify. Something like:

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var buffer = ....
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('bla.js');
wstream.write(buffer);
wstream.pipe(uglify());
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you should be able to call `pipe()` on the readable stream more than once and have the contents sent to two different writable streams.

Eg (dry-coded):

```
var fs = require('fs')
,   uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var rstream = fs.createReadStream('test.log');
rstream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('bla.js'));
rstream.pipe(uglify());
```

Comment: I don't have a file to read from. I have a buffer that received from factor bundle (the example with writable streams): https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle

Comment: As long as `rstream` is a readable stream, I think it should work.

Comment: If you want to help, you have to read https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle Because I am trying to solve something related to their example.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the plugin vinyl-source-stream provides a solution for what you want to do:

```
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
var streamify = require('gulp-streamify')
var browserify = require('browserify')
var fs = require('vinyl-fs');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var bundleStream = browserify('index.js').bundle()

bundleStream
  .pipe(source('index.js'))
  .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
  .pipe(fs.dest('./bla.js'))
```

Comment: Try it and get "TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings"

Comment: I am trying to run gulp-uglify on the output of factor bundle (https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle) can you help?

Comment: Man, I am using factor bundle, which is a plugin of browserify. I solved the situation of browserify alone. I am trying to fix the uglifycation for the factors. I really appreciate a help.

Comment: Do you not see how the bundle is being piped to gulp-uglify before being written? Perhaps review the vinyl-source-stream documentation directly: https://github.com/hughsk/vinyl-source-stream

Comment: I've read vinyl-source-stream documentation several times. .This is not the answer to what I am looking, trust me. Did you read factor-bundle's documentation?